# JOIN Call table to grouping by Origination and Destination

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

[image: Call system]

### It's a call system.

#### tables structure and data sample :

**tbl_countries**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_countries
(
    country_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Austria');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Brazil');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Denmark');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('France');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Lebanon');
```

**tbl_destination_clients**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_destination_clients
(
    des_client_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    des_client varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_destination_clients_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES tbl_countries (country_id)
);
CREATE INDEX country_id ON tbl_destination_clients (country_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('961123456', 5);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('55123456', 2);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('45123456', 3);
```

**tbl_origination_clients**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_origination_clients
(
    orig_client_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orig_client varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_origination_clients_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES tbl_countries (country_id)
);
CREATE INDEX country_id ON tbl_origination_clients (country_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_origination_clients (orig_client, country_id) VALUES ('33123456', 4);
INSERT INTO tbl_origination_clients (orig_client, country_id) VALUES ('43123456', 1);
```

**tbl_calls**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_calls
(
    call_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orig_client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    des_client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    call_duration int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_calls_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (orig_client_id) REFERENCES tbl_origination_clients (orig_client_id),
    CONSTRAINT tbl_calls_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (des_client_id) REFERENCES tbl_destination_clients (des_client_id)
);
CREATE INDEX des_client_id ON tbl_calls (des_client_id);
CREATE INDEX orig_client_id ON tbl_calls (orig_client_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 3, 6);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (2, 4, 9);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 1, 10);
```

#### Attemps :

I try to use JOIN between the same table `tbl_calls`, but it's not working ;(

But the Result of this sample data must be :

```
Origination  Destination  SUM(call_duration)
------------+------------+----------------
France       Brazil       11 -> (5+6)
Austria      Denmark      9
France       Lebanon      10
```

Thank you @forpas

**Query with adapted join column**

```
select
  co.country Origination,
  cd.country Destination,
  sum(c.call_duration) TotalDuration
from tbl_calls c 
inner join tbl_destination_clients d on d.des_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_origination_clients o on o.orig_client_id = c.orig_client_id
inner join tbl_countries cd on cd.country_id = d.country_id
inner join tbl_countries co on co.country_id = o.country_id
group by   
  co.country,
  cd.country;
```

Comment: *"I want to"* is not a way to ask a question. Please show us 1) your attempts 2) table structure **as text** 3) data sample 4) expected output

Comment: thank you @Cid, the new explain is good ?

Answer (score 1):

With grouping after multiple joins (`tbl_countries` must be joined twice for destination and origination) 
and sum over `call_duration`:

```
select
  co.country Origination,
  cd.country Destination,
  sum(c.call_duration) TotalDuration
from tbl_calls c 
inner join tbl_destination_clients d on d.des_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_origination_clients o on o.orig_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_countries cd on cd.country_id = d.country_id
inner join tbl_countries co on co.country_id = o.country_id
group by   
  co.country,
  cd.country;
```

Comment: The sample data you posted do not produce your expected results. The values (1, 3, 5) and (1, 3, 6) that you insert into tbl_calls, point to ('33123456', 4) in tbl_origination_clients and ('45123456', 3) in tbl_destination_clients, meaning countries 4 and 3 which are: France and Denmark, not France and Brazil.

Comment: Also in these values from tbl_calls (2, 4, 9) 4 is for des_client_id, but there is not des_client_id = 4 in tbl_destination_clients.